# Rails: how to write a better association condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

In Rails 2.3.8 I have 2 models News and User.

In my app **I'd like to be able to show to each registered user only the news he has not still read**.  In the homepage each piece of news should be presented in a box and the user should be able to click on a "X" and hide that news forever (just for his profile).

One way to do this is to have a User_news model and, each time a piece of news is created generate a record in the User_news model for each user and update the linking record for each user with a "Read" field set to True.  Then create an association in the User model like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :unread_news, :through => :user_news, :source => :news, :conditions => 'read IS NOT TRUE'
```

The problem with this approach is that if I have thousands of users in my app, each time I publish a piece of news I need to create thousands of records in my user_news table.

My question is: is it possible to write an association between the User and the News model that tells Rails something like:

"Unread news for each User are every existing News EXCEPT for the ones that appear in the User_news table"?

Anyway how would you approach my goal?

Thanks,
Augusto

Comment: One way to do this is to have an "unread news" named scope that selects every news record in the news tables and subtracts from this group the news linked to the user via the news_users table.

Comment: How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

seems you are talking about NoSQL solution. If you sure about it, try MongoDB